# Java - Removing my 'worm' from an arraylist and JFrame

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe

My program creates randomly colored and sized worms that expand on a JFrame/JPanel. As time progresses the worms are constantly expanding in random directions. When new worm is clicked a new worm is born somewhere on the screen.

Where my issue arises:

I having trouble understanding how I would then kill worms. When I click the kill worm button I want the worm to disappear (OR stop growing) on screen and it to be removed from the arraylist. I have no idea how to even begin doing this. I personally think removing an instance of the arraylist would be the best way, but how would I go about actually removing the worm from the screen.

Below is my code:

Main Class:

```
package Main;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadFrame myFrame = new ThreadFrame();
    myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setTitle("Worms! - Jonathan Perron");
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    myFrame.setResizable(false);
}
}
```

ThreadFrame Class:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ThreadFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

int index = 0;
JButton btnNewWorm, btnKillWorm;
JPanel myPanel2 = new JPanel();
ArrayList<DrawThread> worms = new ArrayList<DrawThread>();

public JPanel getMyPanel2(){
    return this.myPanel2;
}

public ThreadFrame() {
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    btnNewWorm = new JButton("New Worm");
    btnKillWorm = new JButton("Kill Worm");
    myPanel.setBounds(0, 400, 640, 80);
    myPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    myPanel2.setSize(new Dimension(640, 400));
    myPanel2.setLayout(null);
    myPanel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    btnNewWorm.setBounds(100, 410, 200, 30);
    btnKillWorm.setBounds(340, 410, 200, 30);
    add(btnNewWorm);
    add(btnKillWorm);
    add(myPanel2);
    add(myPanel);
    btnNewWorm.addActionListener(this);
    btnKillWorm.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent AE) {
    if(AE.getSource() == btnNewWorm){
        DrawThread dw = new DrawThread(myPanel2);
        worms.add(dw);
        System.out.println("New worm!");
    }
    if(AE.getSource() == btnKillWorm){ 
        //stop worms from growing or complete disappear from JFrame
        System.out.println("Kill worm!");
    }
}

}
```

DrawThread Class:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawThread extends Thread implements Runnable{

Random rand = new Random();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
Graphics2D g, graph;
private int sleepTime, wormDiameter, hue, saturation, brightness, randomWidth, randomHeight;

public DrawThread(int sleepTime, int wormDiameter, int hue, int saturation, int brightness, int randomWidth, int randomHeight, JPanel myPanel2) {
    this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
    this.wormDiameter = wormDiameter;
    this.brightness = brightness;
    this.hue = hue;
    this.saturation = saturation;
    this.randomWidth = randomWidth;
    this.randomHeight = randomHeight;
    g = (Graphics2D) myPanel2.getGraphics();
}

public void setColor(int hue){
    this.hue = hue;
}

public int getSleepTime(){
    return sleepTime;
}

public void setSleepTime(int sleepTime){
    this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
}
public DrawThread(JPanel myPanel2){

    //get panel dimensions
    int panelWidth = myPanel2.getWidth();
    int panelHeight = myPanel2.getHeight();

    //worm location
    randomWidth = rand.nextInt(panelWidth);
    randomHeight = rand.nextInt(panelHeight);

    //worm size
    wormDiameter = rand.nextInt(7)+3;

    //worm color 
    hue = rand.nextInt(255);
    saturation = rand.nextInt(255);
    brightness = rand.nextInt(255);
    Color color = new Color(hue, saturation, brightness);

    //sleep
    sleepTime = rand.nextInt(80) + 20;

    //Graphics
    g = (Graphics2D) myPanel2.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(color);
    Ellipse2D.Double ellipse2D = new Ellipse2D.Double(randomWidth, randomHeight, wormDiameter, wormDiameter);
    g.fill(ellipse2D);
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new DrawThread(sleepTime, wormDiameter, hue, saturation, brightness, randomWidth, randomHeight, myPanel2));
    thread1.start();
}

public void run(){
    try { 
        while(true) { 
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            Color color = new Color(hue, saturation, brightness);
            g.setColor(color);
            int addedHeight = 0, addedWidth = 0;
            int random = rand.nextInt(8);

            //determining the worms next move location
            if(random == 0){ addedWidth = 0;  addedHeight = 1;  } //North
            if(random == 1){ addedWidth = 1;  addedHeight = 1;  } //North-East
            if(random == 2){ addedWidth = 1;  addedHeight = 0;  } //East
            if(random == 3){ addedWidth = 1;  addedHeight = -1; } //South-East
            if(random == 4){ addedWidth = 0;  addedHeight = -1; } //South
            if(random == 5){ addedWidth = -1; addedHeight = -1; } //South-West
            if(random == 6){ addedWidth = -1; addedHeight = 0;  } //West
            if(random == 7){ addedWidth = -1; addedHeight = 1;  } //North-West

            //Prevent worms from getting off the screen
            if(randomHeight >= 480){ addedHeight = -1; }
            if(randomHeight <= 0){ addedHeight = 1; }
            if(randomWidth >= 640){ addedWidth = -1; }
            if(randomWidth <= 0){ addedWidth = 1; }

            randomWidth += addedWidth;
            randomHeight += addedHeight;
            Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(randomWidth, randomHeight, wormDiameter, wormDiameter);
            g.fill(e);
            }
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR!");
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String result = "SleepTime: " + sleepTime + "\nWorm Diameter: " + wormDiameter
            + "\nHue: " + hue + "\nSaturation: " + saturation + "\nBrightness: "
            + brightness + "\nWidth: " + randomWidth + "\nHeight: " + randomHeight;
    return result;
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

EDIT: This is the assignment that my teacher has given to write this program.

===========================================================================

In this assignment, we’re going to write a program that draws images of “worms” in a window. The 
worms will grow with time, moving in random directions. Each worm will be a different color and will 
grow at a different rate. A separate Thread object will manage the drawing of each worm. Here’s an 
example of what the window will look like after two worms have grown for a while.

Write a class called ThreadFrame that extends JFrame. This class should include a main method that 
creates one instance of this class. This should produce a GUI with an appearance similar to what you see 
above. Make the window 640 by 480 pixels, and do not allow the user to resize it. Add two JPanels to 
the content pane, a white one in the center region on which the threads will be drawn, and a gray one in 
the south region to hold the JButtons marked “New Worm” and “Kill Worm”.

Add an action listener to the “New Worm” button, so that when you click on it, it creates a new instance 
of a class called DrawThread (to be described shortly), adds it to an ArrayList, and starts it. Add an action 
listener to the “Kill Worm” button, so that when you click on it, it removes the first DrawThread from 
the ArrayList and interrupts it.

The class DrawThread extends Thread, and does most of the work of the program. This class will draw 
on the upper panel of the ThreadFrame, so a reference to this panel must be passed to the constructor 
of DrawThread, when this constructor is called from ThreadFrame. The constructor should perform the 
following tasks:

Assign the JPanel reference (received as an argument) to an instance variable of this object. 
Get the graphics context for the JPanel (use the getGraphics method), cast it to type Graphics2D, and 
assign it to an instance variable. 
Determine the width and height of this JPanel, and save these values. 
Create a Color object, with randomly-chosen values for the three arguments to set the red, green, and 
blue intensities, and assign this object to an instance variable. 
Randomly choose a sleep time for this thread, between 20 and 100 milliseconds. This will determine 
how rapidly the image grows.

Comment: Your code breaks Swing threading rules and would be much better served by your using a Swing Timer and not trying to make Swing calls in a background thread off of the Swing event thread. Also, you should draw in either a BufferedImage that is displayed in the JPanel's paintComponent method or draw directly inside of the paintComponent method. Your way of drawing via calling `getGraphics()` on a component is quite brittle and risky.

Comment: Next I would extract out the logic behind the worm out of the GUI. Create a Worm class that holds all the information necessary for representing a single Worm object, give it a `start()` method, perhaps a `grow()` method, a `stop() method and a `kill()` method. Then have your JButton's ActionListener call appropriate methods and your Timer's ActionListener call its appropriate methods. Give your GUI as many Worm objects as you need, and wire your buttons and timer to alter their behaviors.

Comment: I completely agree the things mentioned above. My teacher specifically asks us to use getGraphics() and threading. How can I properly clean up my code?

Comment: Post your exact requirements word for word please.

Comment: Also, to see how brittle your graphics are, run your program, and in the middle of your run, minimize and then restore your program. What happens to the drawings that were on the screen after you do this?

Comment: I'll edit the post and add the outline from my teacher.

Comment: Interesting! The worms on the program disappear, thanks for pointing this out! Honestly, after finally handing in this assignment I will be reviewing better ways to make this program better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your instructions

> Write a class called ThreadFrame that extends JFrame. This class should include a main method that creates one instance of this class. This should produce a GUI with an appearance similar to what you see above. Make the window 640 by 480 pixels, and do not allow the user to resize it. Add two JPanels to the content pane, a white one in the center region on which the threads will be drawn, and a gray one in the south region to hold the JButtons marked “New Worm” and “Kill Worm”.

OK, you've got this.

> Add an action listener to the “New Worm” button, so that when you click on it, it creates a new instance of a class called DrawThread (to be described shortly), adds it to an ArrayList, and starts it.

Again, you've done this.

> Add an action listener to the “Kill Worm” button, so that when you click on it, it removes the first DrawThread from the ArrayList and interrupts it.

Break it down:

- Get the most recent worm from the ArrayList -- you would use two ArrayList methods, `size()` and `get(...)` to achieve this. Give it a try.
- Then interrupt the thread. Once you get the object from the array list, you will need to call a Thread method on it, and I'm guessing that you'll be able figure out which method, right (read the instructions for this, i.e, "and *interrupts* it")? ;)

---

**Edit**
Note, that his recommendations are not good, and I would not hire your instructor or course director as a Swing programmer if I needed one.

---

**Edit**
Just for grins, here is another way to code this sort of thing. Note that it does not satisfy your assignment requirements (which is one reason I don't hesitate to post it), but it shows what I believe are better Swing behaviors:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyWormMain {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MyWormDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyWormDrawPanel();
      MyWormButtonPanel btnPanel = new MyWormButtonPanel(drawPanel);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Worms");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.getContentPane().add(btnPanel.getMainPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyWormDrawPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 640;
   private static final int PREF_H = 480;
   private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.WHITE;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 50;
   private List<MyWorm> wormList = new ArrayList<>();
   private Timer wormTimer;
   private Random random = new Random();

   public MyWormDrawPanel() {
      setBackground(BACKGROUND);
      wormTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new WormTimerListener());
      wormTimer.start();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      for (MyWorm worm : wormList) {
         worm.draw(g2);
      }
   }

   public void addWorm() {
      int r = random.nextInt(128) + 128;
      int g = random.nextInt(128) + 128;
      int b = random.nextInt(128) + 128;

      int rand = random.nextInt(3);
      switch (rand) {
      case 0:
         r /= 3;
         break;
      case 1:
         g /= 3;
         break;
      case 2:
         b /= 3;

      default:
         break;
      }
      Color color = new Color(r, g, b);

      int x = random.nextInt(PREF_W);
      int y = random.nextInt(PREF_H);
      Point head = new Point(x, y);
      wormList.add(new MyWorm(color, head, PREF_W, PREF_H));
   }

   public void killWorm() {
      if (wormList.size() > 0) {
         wormList.remove(wormList.size() - 1);
      }
   }

   private class WormTimerListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         for (MyWorm worm : wormList) {
            worm.grow();
         }
         repaint();
      };
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyWormButtonPanel {
   private static final int GAP = 15;
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private MyWormDrawPanel drawPanel;

   public MyWormButtonPanel(MyWormDrawPanel drawPanel) {
      this.drawPanel = drawPanel;
      mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, GAP, GAP));
      mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
      mainPanel.add(new JButton(new AddWormAction("Add Worm", KeyEvent.VK_A)));
      mainPanel.add(new JButton(new KillWormAction("Kill Worm", KeyEvent.VK_K)));
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private class AddWormAction extends AbstractAction {

      public AddWormAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         drawPanel.addWorm();
      }
   }

   private class KillWormAction extends AbstractAction {

      public KillWormAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         drawPanel.killWorm();
      }
   }

}

class MyWorm {
   private static final int MAX_DIR = 360;
   private static final int SEG_WIDTH = 20;
   private static final int MAX_RAND_DIR = 60;
   private Color color;
   private List<Point> body = new ArrayList<>();
   private Random random = new Random();
   private int direction;
   private int maxX;
   private int maxY;

   public MyWorm(Color color, Point head, int maxX, int maxY) {
      this.color = color;
      body.add(head);
      direction = random.nextInt(MAX_DIR);
      this.maxX = maxX;
      this.maxY = maxY;
   }

   public void grow() {
      Point lastPt = body.get(body.size() - 1);
      int x = lastPt.x
            + (int) (SEG_WIDTH * 3 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(direction)) / 4.0);
      int y = lastPt.y
            + (int) (SEG_WIDTH * 3 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(direction)) / 4.0);

      if (x < 0) {
         x = maxX - 1;
      } 
      if (x > maxX) {
         x = 0;
      }
      if (y < 0) {
         y = maxY - 1;
      }
      if (y > maxY) {
         y = 0;
      }

      Point nextPoint = new Point(x, y);
      direction += random.nextInt(MAX_RAND_DIR) - MAX_RAND_DIR / 2;

      body.add(nextPoint);
   }

   public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
      Graphics2D g2b = (Graphics2D) g2.create();
      g2b.setColor(color);
      for (Point p : body) {
         int x = p.x - SEG_WIDTH / 2;
         int y = p.y - SEG_WIDTH / 2;
         int width = SEG_WIDTH;
         int height = SEG_WIDTH;
         g2b.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
      }
      g2b.dispose();
   }

}
```

Comment: Haha of course, of course. I guess it just comes down to my comprehension skills... lol. Thanks for all the help you have provided, I'll be continuing from what I've got.

Comment: I want to thank you for all your help! I just finished successfully interrupting the worms and it works flawlessly! Thanks!